# How to clean a column with names inserted with different formats (separated by commas, by dots, etc.)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Imagine that you have a dataset with two columns, an id and a name, but the column name was inserted manually and has names typed in different formats. Some are separated with dots instead of blank spaces. Others put the surname first, then a comma, and then the first name. Some rows have middle names or even name titles.

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ellie Joella |
| 2 | Antonio.Chaz |
| 3 | Dr. Ian Coretta |
| 4 | Doe, John |
| 5 | Marie.Eliza.Grey |
| 6 | Mason, Lary O |
| 7 | Winfred, Mr. Barry |
| 8 | Andrea.T.B.Shaw |

How would you clean this column so the result would be something like : <name title (if inserted)>  <middle names (if inserted)> .

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ellie Joella |
| 2 | Antonio Chaz |
| 3 | Dr. Ian Coretta |
| 4 | John Doe |
| 5 | Marie Eliza Grey |
| 6 | Lary O Mason |
| 7 | Mr. Barry Winfred |
| 8 | Andrea T B Shaw |

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `replace` with a dict of regex:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].replace({r'(?<!Dr|Mr)(\.\s*)': ' ', r'([^,]+)\s*,\s*(.*)': r'\2 \1'}, regex=True)
print(df)

# Output
   ID               Name
0   1       Ellie Joella
1   2       Antonio Chaz
2   3    Dr. Ian Coretta
3   4           John Doe
4   5   Marie Eliza Grey
5   6       Lary O Mason
6   7  Mr. Barry Winfred
7   8    Andrea T B Shaw
```

Comment: Corralien but user want to exclude `Mr,Ms,Dr` but in ur case they are alos replaced

Comment: Yeah now it's fine thanks for edits

Comment: Thanks @Bhargav. I fixed this with a negative lookbehind. https://regex101.com/r/gGXkJT/1

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the split method. you have to do several depending on what the text contains. I would first check if there are spaces in the text, and split the string after them.
You would also need to make a list of exceptions Mr. Dr. etc. and if the first string after splitting is any of them then merge it with the second one.

**You could try making the function**

```
def person(data):
    test = ('dr.', 'mr.', 'etc.')
    try:
        space = val.index(' ')
    except:
        space = None
        
    if space:
        pers = data.split(' ')
    else:
        pers = data.split('.')
```

and next check all You want
But how to check if a word is a first or last name I don't know